# FragmentStatePagerAdapter items don't load

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-pageradapter

In my main activity I have multiple Fragments that you can navigate through a bottom navigation (Replace a FrameLayout container in main activity XML)

One of those Fragments contains a ViewPager that should show multiple Fragments (MyFragment) using a FragmentStatePagerAdapter (MyAdapter).

First time I open that Fragment it works just fine but when I navigate to a different one and then come back the first two Fragments in the Pager are grey and unpopulated. Anyone got an idea what the problem might be?

The Adapter is set up like this:
This is called in `onFragmentViewCreated`

```
private void setUpHeaderPager() {
    featuredAdapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
    myPager.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    pageIndicatorView.setViewPager(myPager);
    pageIndicatorView.setAnimationType(AnimationType.WORM);
    compositeSubscription.add(apiService.getMyPOJOs()
            .subscribeOn(networkScheduler)
            .observeOn(uiScheduler)
            .subscribe(new Action1<List<MyPOJO>>() {
                @Override
                public void call(List<MyPOJO> myPOJOs) {
                    myAdapter.setItems(myPOJOs);
                    pageIndicatorView.setCount(myPOJOs.size());
                    myPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                    pageIndicatorView.setSelection(0);
                }
            }, new Action1<Throwable>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Throwable throwable) {
                    throwable.printStackTrace();
                }
            }));
}
```

And this is what the Adapter looks like:

```
private class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private List<SomePOJO> items = new ArrayList<>(0);

    public void setItems(@Nonnull List<Collection> items) {
        this.items = items;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    FeaturedReleasesAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return MyFragment.newInstance(items.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }
}
```

Just in case the relevant code of MyFragment:

```
public class FeaturedReleaseFragment extends BaseFragment {

private MyPOJO someObject = null;

// Bind some views

public static MyFragment newInstance(MyPOJO someObject) {
    MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
    fragment.someObject = someObject;
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_fragment, container, false);

    ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView);

    populate();

    return rootView;
}

private void populate() {
    if (MyPOJO != null) {
        // set some text and load images
    }
}
```

`onFragmentViewCreated` is called just fine, the adapters `getItem` is not...

Comment: How many items are in this list `List<MyPOJO> myPOJOs` each time? Same amount everytime `onNext()` is called in your Rx subscription ?

Comment: @MarkKeen yes and setting the items in the adapter works fine also the pageindicator updates approriately but `getItem` is not called so the Fragment doesn't get populated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be how you're navigating between the bottom navigation fragments and subsequently whats happening with their lifecycle.

If you are using `.replace` on the `FragmentTransaction`, try using `.show` and `.hide` instead.

Something like the following might do it:

```
public void navigateToFragment( Fragment frag ) {
     FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    transaction.hide(currentFragment);

    if ( !fragment.isAdded() ) {
        transaction.add(R.id.container,fragment)
    } else if ( !fragment.isHidden() ) {
        transaction.show(fragment);
    }
    transation.commit();
}
```